# How to send plain HTML from Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

My `index.html` file has this:

```
<input name='qwe'>
{{qwe}}
```

I want that `{{qwe}}` to be sent literally, i.e. not replaced by variables populated by the server.

How should I do that? I was thinking in this pseudo code:

```
app.get('*',function(req,res){
  fs.read('index.html',function(data){
    res.send(data)
  })
})
```

But I suppose I don't know how is this usually done. Maybe I have to use a predefined Express.js template engine:

```
app.engine('html', ...)
```

But I don't know what part of the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.engine) to read. I also took a look at [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/), but all of these templates, seem to be, "template engines", do I really need a template engine?

I want to send a file as it is.

By the way, I am doing all of this because I want to work with Angular.js, but for experimentation purposes I am not using [MEAN](http://mean.io), I assume MEAN has to do something like this.

## Update

I am trying this:

```
app.get('*',function(req, res){
  require('fs').readFile('views/index.html', 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(data);
  })
  // res.sendfile('views/index.html');
});
```

But file is downloaded and not rendered, any advice? I suppose I have to set Content-Type or another header?

Comment: Just use `res.sendfile()`.

Comment: I used sendfile, but `{{}}`s get replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Express when server will get a `GET` request of `/` it will search for /public/index.html serve that as response. You don't have to add router for that `/`.

So you can just put your `index.html` in `public` folder and hit `/` from browser. you should get it.

Comment: When I remove the route I get `Cannot GET /`, I think maybe you are referring to MEAN, do you? I suppose in plain express I have to configure it to search in public?

Comment: @juanpastas sorry but din't you configured this line in your app.js `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: if you not you'll have to.

Answer (score -1):

I think the code you pasted is OK. It will send the file raw content.

Comment: does it have drawbacks? I don't see any.